# rendezvous hashing algorithm new node causing issues

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have three cache servers and use HRW to hash.

- When a client sends requests
- A server is chosen depending upon the highest weight (hash of request and server).
- If request is not found on that, request is forwarded to back-end server and result it fetched, stored in that cache and forwarded to client. (A similar request in future will be fetched from the cache.)

The issue is when for request R1 a result is stored in Server 2, let's suppose. Now let's say 2 new servers come up. Now, if we send R1 again, and it finds weight just like before and weight of any of the new server comes out to be more than previous values, then it won't fetch me a result.

How should I respond to this issue?

Comment: You need to provide your code here, and details of what errors you are having.

Comment: Hi Mikkel, not exactly getting any errors. Its just that if weight of new servers is more than original server, the request doesn't go to the actual server. Do you want me to explain in detail ?

Comment: Stack overflow is a site where we help you solve problems, and the easiest way to do that is post snippets of code, and errors that you are getting. We can't help with something as vague as this, because it will take too long. We  need you to make your best efforts to solve the problem, and if you really can't solve it, then lay it out for someone to look at the code and provide a fix

Comment: _.. weight just like before_ and _weight of any of the new server_ sounds like you're calculating the hashes independently, which would be wrong. On the other hand, the second bullet point sounds like you're doing it correctly, calculating a _combined_ hash. Is the combination correct, e.g. no cutting off anywhere? Do you cache hash results? This could be an error. Could you solve the issure?